# Losing response object in async callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Alright, I've been searching high and low, and apparently I am missing a trick.

Standard NodeJS/Express combination, doing a database call (thistakesalotoftime()) which may take a while to complete. If I get a new request while the first one is in progress, the render result from the first task is sometimes streamed to the response from request #2.

Mind, I am somewhat fresh to NodeJS, coming from a mostly PHP background. Never had that problem with Apache :)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');


function thistakesalotoftime(cb) {
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'bob',
    password : 'uncle'
  });

  connection.connect(function(err) {
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
  });

  connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    cb(results.solution);
  });
}


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  thistakesalotoftime(function(data) {
    res.send(data);
  });
})


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

It happens even with this extremely simplified app instance. Do please enlighten me. Any and all tips welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code (that is, the minimum code needed to replicate the issue).

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you mean by "the render result is streamed"? Do you mean that the second request gets the data that the first request asked for, and vice versa?

Comment: @Hamms That is exactly what happens. Seems to be a race of sorts. Request #1 asks for a specific data item, and request #2 asks for a different one. Works 99% of the time, just sometimes requestor #2 ends up with the answer #1 should have gotten. #1 will in that case just sit there and eventually time out, which has me thinking that the response object was overwritten. The database behind this is a very large MySQL, and the specific query takes about 1s to complete.

Comment: What's your actual `thistakesalotoftime` function? The code provided is not enough to reproduce

Comment: @Hamms Added. Simplified query used (boss asked for scrubbing) in the example, but it shows what is going on.

Comment: It looks like you are missing `connection.end()`. Don't see how the code you show could cause the problem you describe.  There must be more to it than what you show.  FYI, `throw error` is not acceptable error handling.  That will not do anything useful from inside an async callback.

Comment: Could the problem be on the client side as well? What are you testing this with?

Comment: @Bergi Two shell sessions running curl in a loop. As straight-forward as can be, I think.

Comment: And you say it happens even with the above code? What different results would you get?